# Find one section in a for loop based on url

Tags: entries

I am new at Craft CMS so have patience with me (and my English).

I don't know if I am doing this right, but I have a link (URL) from my index.html, and I want to display the specific content on the _entry.html.

Index.html

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news') %}
    <h3><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h3>
{% endfor %}
```

And when I click on that link I want only to display the content related to that `entry.url`.

If I click the link now, all my entries will show in _entry.html.

_entry.html

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').type('news') %}
    <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

I just want to show the specific content for that section.

---

Update:

I tested this and it worked:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').type('news').slug(craft.request.getSegment(2)) %}
```

But I don't know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `{{ entry.title }}` on your dynamic _entry template to output that specific title. You were looping through all the news entries again on the dynamic _entry template and listing each one. Any other custom fields on that page/section can be accessed simply by `{{ entry.myCustomFieldName }}`.